# Array Density and Sparse arrays

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Project_2 {

public static void main(String[] args) // TODO Auto-generated      methodstub
{
    int userLength;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a length for an Array : ");
    userLength = input.nextInt();

    while (userLength < 1)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a length for an Array : ");
        userLength = input.nextInt();
    }

    int [] arrayFirst  = new int [userLength];
    System.out.print("The length is: " + arrayFirst.length + "\n");
    Random randomInt = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayFirst.length; i++ )
    {
        arrayFirst[i] = randomInt.nextInt(100001);
    }
}
```

> Write a Java program that first prompts the user for an integer array
>   length and a “double-precision”array density.  You will use these
>   values to create the arrays for the experimentas below.Also prompt the
>   user to re-enter values(s) if they are outside of the expected range:
>   the length of the array should be a positive integer,and the density
>   should be of the type double and in the range [0.0, 1.0].
>
> Write a method which takes an integer length and an array density of
>   type double as arguments and returns a new array of type
>   intrepresenting a dense array.  For each entry in the array, compare
>   the density with a random number in the range [0.0, 1.0) (i.e., 0.0 up
>   to,but not including,1.0) to determine whether or not the entry should
>   be 0(hint: see the java.util.Random class).  If the entry should be 0,
>   simply populate the entry as such.  Ifthe entry should be non-zero,
>   populate it with a random integer on the range [1, 1000000] (i.e., 1
>   through 1 million).In this way, specifying an array length of 100 and
>   a density of 0.25 would result in an arrayof length 100 with on
>   average 75% of its values equal to 0.

I have a good understanding on the first section of this problem but I'm completely clueless on the density aspect of the problem. Then I filled the array with random numbers just to get a feel for that. However I'm completely clueless what I should be doing when it comes to the density aspect of this question. All I know is that the density of an array is defined as the ratio of the number of the non-zero elements over the total number of all the elements in this array. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to write the code for you, but you basically need to do one of two things for each field of the array:

- Generate a random number x between 0 and 1. If x is greater than or equal to the density, set this field to 0.
- Otherwise, if x is less than the density, set the field to a random value between 1 and 1000000.